# Tslint rule equivalent in eslint

Tags: eslint, tslint

Tslint has an rule no-string-literal rule is there an equivalent rule in eslint as well

I am using eslint and when I do ng lint it gives me error "object access via string literals is disallowed ", I will fix it manually now but I want to set rule in eslint config file so no one else working on code makes same mistake

Answer (score 2):

The equivalent rule in Eslint is `dot-notation` .
See [this page](https://eslint.org/docs/rules/dot-notation) reference.

Also [here](https://github.com/typescript-eslint/typescript-eslint/blob/master/packages/eslint-plugin/ROADMAP.md) is a corresponding table of rules between TSlint and Eslint.